# npm install dependencies of a git submodule

Tags: git, gruntjs, handlebars.js, npm

I've got a git project with handlebars.js as a submodule.  I will provide here a bare-bones example - the full project is more complicated with dojo tasks and deployment steps that aren't relevant here.

```
$ mkdir handlebarstest ; cd handlebarstest ; git init
$ mkdir src ; git add src
$ git submodule add https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js.git src/handlebars.js
```

Our `package.json` doesn't mention handlebars.js, just grunt:

```
{
  "name": "handlebarstest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-run-grunt": "latest"
  }
}
```

In this project's history, our install and build procedure has been:

```
$ npm install   # install dependencies in package.json
$ grunt init    # run the 'init' task which initialises git submodules
$ grunt build   # run the 'build' task which compiles dojo etc.
```

Having done a fresh clone of our project, say on our build server, git submodules need to be initialised, and we control that from grunt, so we must install grunt first, then run a task to init submodules, including the troublesome handlebars.js.

We do `npm install` and install grunt, and `grunt init` which fetches handlebars.js including its `package.json`.  So the root of our problem is that the `package.json` is not available when the top level `npm install` is run.

Our Gruntfile.js knows how to call the Gruntfile.js in handlebars.js:

```
/*jshint node:true */
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    /*jshint camelcase: false */
    var path = require('path');

    grunt.initConfig({
        clean: [ 'dist' ],
        run_grunt: {
            options: {

            },
            handlebars_build: {
                options: {
                    log: true
                },
                src: [ 'src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js' ],
                task: 'build'
            },
            handlebars_amd: {
                options: {
                    log: true
                },
                src: [ 'src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js' ],
                task: 'amd'
            }
        }
    });

    // var handlebarsLink= grunt.registerTask('handlebarsLink', function () {
    //  var done = this.async(),
    //      child = grunt.util.spawn({
    //          cmd: 'npm',
    //          args: [ 'link', 'src/handlebars.js' ]
    //      }, function (error) {
    //          if (error) {
    //              grunt.warn(error);
    //              done(false);
    //              return;
    //          }
    //          done();
    //      });

    //  child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    //      grunt.log.write(data);
    //  });
    //  child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    //      grunt.log.error(data);
    //  });
    // });
    var submodules;
    if (grunt.file.exists(__dirname, '.git')) {
        submodules = grunt.registerTask('submodules', function () {
            var done = this.async(),
                child = grunt.util.spawn({
                    cmd: 'git',
                    args: [ 'submodule', 'update', '--init', '--recursive' ]
                }, function (error) {
                    if (error) {
                        grunt.warn(error);
                        done(false);
                        return;
                    }
                    done();
                });

            child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                grunt.log.write(data);
            });
            child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                grunt.log.error(data);
            });
        });
    }
    var init = submodules ? [ 'submodules'/*, 'handlebarsLink'*/ ] : [];
    grunt.registerTask('init', init);
    grunt.registerTask('default', 'build');
    grunt.registerTask('build', init.concat([ 'clean', 'run_grunt:handlebars_build', 'run_grunt:handlebars_amd' ]));

    grunt.loadTasks(path.join(__dirname, 'grunt'));
    grunt.loadTasks(path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'intern', 'tasks'));
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-run-grunt');
};
```

Running grunt fails because it recurses into handlebars.js but the module dependencies in its package.json have not been installed.

```
Running "run_grunt:handlebars_build" (run_grunt) task
--> starting  "src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js"
--> reporting "src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js"
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-concat" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-connect" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-copy" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-requirejs" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-jshint" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-uglify" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "grunt-saucelabs" not found. Is it installed?
  |  >> Local Npm module "es6-module-packager" not found. Is it installed?
  |  Loading "metrics.js" tasks...ERROR
  |  >> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
  |  Loading "publish.js" tasks...ERROR
  |  >> Error: Cannot find module 'underscore'
  |  Loading "version.js" tasks...ERROR
  |  >> Error: Cannot find module 'async'
  |  Warning: Task "clean" not found. Use --force to continue.
  |  
  |  Aborted due to warnings.
  |  
--> failed "src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js" (304ms)
--> failed handlebars_build @ "src/handlebars.js/Gruntfile.js"

Warning: 1 gruntfile failed and completed 0 (308ms)
 Use --force to continue.
```

Solutions might be:

1. Use `npm link` somehow in our top level `package.json` to do
   something clever with a script hook after `npm install` has
   finished.  This seems impossible, because the
   `handlebars.js/package.json` isn't going to be available until well
   after `npm install` has finished.
2. Put a manual step before
   `run_grunt:handlebars_build` to recurse into `src/handlebars.js` and run
   `npm install` in that directory.  This seems more manual than I
   would expect.
3. Put a step before `run_grunt:handlebars_build` that
   installs dependencies from `src/handlebars.js/package.json` into the
   project's top level node_modules directory, which might then be
   picked up when running Gruntfile.js inside `src/handlebars.js` (this
   may require that there is no node_modules directory in
   `src/handlebars.js` - my knowledge of npm and node_modules is not
   great).
4. Give up on trying to build handlebars.js as part of our
   project's build, remove the `src/handlebars.js` submodule from the
   project, and just add built files as plain files in its place.  This
   would be a shame because you lose the benefits of tracking a
   project's versions intelligently via the git submodule approach.

Some advice would be appreciated on the best way forward.

Comment: I guess I'm missing why you are "building" handlebars in the first place? You say to "track a project's versions intelligently", but I'm not sure what you mean by that. How are you tracking the versions? And why? Separately from that, are you using Handlebars only on the client, or in a precompilation step? If only on the client, perhaps switching that dependency to something like [Bower](http://bower.io) would be better?

Comment: @jakerella by 'tracking versions' I simply mean that we can have a specific version of the project available at a time, no other reason.. basically what the package.json 'dependency' line would give us, but managed in this case via the git submodule revision.  It is for a precompilation step.. our ``grunt build`` needs to run the Dojo build process, which collects files in the build directory (including handlebars and its AMD pieces) and prepares them as a 'dist' web app.  Perhaps Bower is the right way forward for us, I will try it.  Thank you for the tip.

Comment: Hmm... ok, so if it's necessary as a build dependency, then I guess I don't follow why you can't include it using npm and the `package.json` file. Sorry, I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what.

Answer (score 45):

To ensure your submodule's dependencies are installed whenever you install your main repo's dependencies, you need to modify your main package.json.

Assuming your submodule is called 'common' and sits under `src/common` and its package.json is in `src/common`, then,

You should run `npm install --save file:src/common` and it will add the dependency to your `package.json` (or you can add by yourself, just append to your `dependencies` key the key:value of `"common": "file:src/common",`

Running `npm install` afterwards, will install all dependencies in the main module and submodule.

These steps will also help solve the issue in continuous deployment environments.

Comment: this answer is the more useful one and should be the accepted answer

Comment: this answer is really helpful!

Answer (score 5):

this might be of some help to someone stumbling over this question like i did during my research regarding a similar question:

My solution uses the `grunt` plugin `grunt-run` to run `npm install` in the submodule directory (installing its dependencies into its own `node_modules` directory: that would be `src/handlebars.js/node_modules/` in your case).

In my case i needed to compile the TypeScript files using a `grunt` task inside the sub-module afterwards. I solved this using the plugin `grunt-submodule`.

The

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-clean" not found. Is it installed?`
```

errors seem to appear if `grunt` is being executed in the wrong working directory - if you've managed to install the dependencies before.

**Example:**

Only the sub-module uses `grunt-contrib-clean` to clean its build artifacts. You've installed the sub-modules requirements (inside its directory) but you run `grunt clean` in the parents directory. The node module is not known in this place.

Hope that helps,

Markus

---

These tasks are of course run from within `grunt`, integrated into my build/development life-cycle.

**References:**

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-run
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-submodule